# VB.NET Consuming web service written for glassfish: SoapHeaderException

Tags: java, vb.net, web-services, soap, glassfish

Wrote a 'webservice' with Netbeans wizard, runs on glassfish. I added a reference using the wsdl to my .NET client, VB if it makes any difference.

I clearly have no idea what is going on, as I am encountering some brick walls.

The issue is a SoapHeaderException.

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(
         SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, 
         Boolean asyncCall)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(
         String methodName,  Object[] parameters)
at WSClient.WSClient.localhost.DatabaseGateService.createCustomerTable(String xml)
          in C:\Project\WSClient\Web References\localhost\Reference.vb:line 40
at WSClient.USAHWSClientConsumer.TestCustomer() in
          C:\Project\WSClient\Client\WSConsumer.vb:line 22
```

The web service itself is simple:

```
@WebService()
public class DatabaseGate {
    private MySQLManagerImp manager;

    public DatabaseGate(){
        manager = new MySQLManagerImp();
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName = "createCustomerTable")
    public void createCustomerTable(@WebParam(name = "xml") String xml) {
        manager.createCustomersTable(xml);
    }
}
```

It takes an xml string, as I did not want to pass in an abomination of arguments.

I attempt to consume the service by simply instantiating the web reference:

```
Dim ws As localhost.DatabaseWS = New localhost.DatabaseWS
// Create the xml string
Dim qbCustomerQueryRS As String = qbQuery.GetCustomerQueryXML()
Dim processedCustomerXML As String = 
    customerResponseParser.GetAllCustomerDatabaseFriendlyXML(qbCustomerQueryRS)

ws.createCustomerTable(processedCustomerXML)
```

I've tried writing the string in a soap envelope, but still receive the same message. So passing a string is kaputt, as it should be; why would the WS know to parse a string, and simply instantiating and calling the method from the object as if it were local isn't working the way I think it does.

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the WSDL references `com/mysql/jdbc/Connection`, which is not a class known on the .NET side. If you have control over the Web Service, add annotations to avoid serialization of external class references (like `com/mysql/jdbc/Connection`). If you don't, simply download the WSDL to a text file, edit it manually to remove such classes/attributes, and re-create the reference pointing to the edited file. You can change the endpoints in Web.config later.

Comment: Looking at ?wsdl, I don't see any direct references to the Connection class. I do have control over the web service. I created a very simple WS with no external references, and it works, so you are right. Unfortunately I have to wonder why it matters what local dependencies the WS is sitting on from a client perspective; all it ought to care about is receiving a string right? Any way, I don't know how to add the proper annotations. What is being abstracted from me by the code wizards that creates dependencies when swapping SOAP messages? Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the reason I was receiving

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
```

was similar to Diego's answer (thank you for pointing me in the right direction): A reference problem.

I assumed my WS deployment worked correctly because I had tested the method that executed, but only assuming the data I needed successfully transmitted over the wire.

Testing another angle using glassfish revealed:

```
Service invocation threw an exception with message : null; Refer to the server log for more details
```

Checking the server log, the answer was obvious:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
```

I had forgotten to add the jar to com/mysql/jdbc/Connection.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to reply to your comment. I am glad you figured it out. Upvote.